# jquery input field changes all php loop items value in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, loops

I am trying to create a custom wordpress template for products. For which I need to update the Total quantity when 2 sub-quantity is increased or decreased. Also the value of total quantity will be multiplied with price.

Let's say: 
**sub-quantity-1 value = 2** and **sub-quantity-2 value = 3,**
So **Total quantity value = 5** and **price is 5 x $100 = $500**

*The problem is I am generating this input fields using wordpress loop, so all the inputs have same class & name.*

Lets say: I am increasing **sub-quantity** for **PRODUCT 1** which increases all **Total Quantity** for **PRODUCT 1** to **PRODUCT 100**

***PHP CODE:***

```
    <?php $wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'post__in'       => array( 481, 478, 934, 178 ),
        'posts_per_page' => 15,
        'offset'         => 0, 
        'orderby'        => '', 
        'order'          => 'ASC' ) ); 
    ?>
    <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :  while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :  $wp_querys->the_post();
    global $product;
    $product = get_product( get_the_ID() ); 
    ?>
    <table>

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Total Quantity</th>
                <th>Button</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="products-container">

            <tr class="product-<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>"> 

                <form action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>" class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

                    <td class="price">

                        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                            <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">
                                <?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>
                            </span>
                            <?php echo $product->get_price() ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>



                    <td class="quantity">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <?php echo qty-sz(); ?>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <?php echo qty-bn(); ?>

                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </td>




                    <td class="quantity-total">
                        <?php woocommerce_quantity_input(); ?>
                    </td>

                    <td class="button">

                        <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0" />
                        <button type="submit" class="button buy-now-btn cart-btn product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" />Add to Cart</button>

                    </td>

                </form>                                       

            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>

    </table>
```

***GENERATED HTML CODE:***

```
                    <table>

                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Note Box</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Choose Your Keyblade</th>
                    <th>Product Total Quantity</th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>

                <tbody>




                    <tr class="product-934" data-role="product"> 

                    <form action="/testsite/wholesale-product-page-template-custom/?add-to-cart=934" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>

                        <td class="image">


                                <img src="https://localhost/testsite/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/placeholder.png" alt="Placeholder" width="150px" height="150px">                      </td>

                            <td class="title">
                                <h3>Group Product</h3>
                            </td>

                            <td class="note">
                                                            <label>Type Your Letter</label><input class="letter-note wh-input" name="_wholesale_letter" value="" maxlength="1" placeholder="TYPE 1 LETTER">                     </td>

                            <td class="price">

                                <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                                    <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">
                                        $                               </span>
                                    786                         </span>

                            </td>



                            <td class="keyblade">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody><tr>
                                        <th>Schlage-SC1</th><td><input class="sc-note wh-input wh-qty" name="_wholesale_sc" value="" type="number"></td>                                </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Kwikset-KW1</th><td><input class="kw-note wh-input wh-qty" name="_wholesale_kw" value="" type="number"></td>                                </tr>
                                </tbody></table>

                            </td>

                            <td class="quantity-field">
                                                            <div class="quantity">
                                    <input step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" type="number">
                                </div>
                            </td>

                            <td class="button">

                                <input name="add-to-cart" value="934" type="hidden">
                                <input name="product_id" value="934" type="hidden">
                                <input name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0" type="hidden">
                                <button type="submit" class="button buy-now-btn cart-btn product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">Add to Cart</button>

                            </td>




                    </tr>
                </tbody>



                        <style>.product-type-variable .summary .price { display: inline-block; } .quantity { display: inline-block; }</style>

                            <tbody><tr class="product-719 variation-722 wrapper" data-role="product"> 
                  <form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product_id="719" data-product_variations="null"></form>   
                    <td class="image">
                        <img src="https://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/151-Sterling-Silver-Pink-Tourmaline.png" alt="Custom Key Blades-722" width="150px" height="150px">              </td>
                    <td class="title">
                        <h3>Custom Key Blades</h3><br>
                        <b>18 K Yellow Gold  </b>
                        </td>

                    <td class="note">
                                            <label>Type Your Letter</label><input class="letter-note wh-input" name="_wholesale_letter" value="" maxlength="1" placeholder="TYPE 1 LETTER">             </td>   
                    <td class="price">
                        <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>1,150.00</span></span>                </td>
                    <td class="keyblade">
                        <table>
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <th>Schlage-SC1</th><td><input class="sc-note wh-input wh-qty" name="_wholesale_sc" value="" type="number"></td>                        </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <th>Kwikset-KW1</th><td><input class="kw-note wh-input wh-qty" name="_wholesale_kw" value="" type="number"></td>                        </tr>
                        </tbody></table>

                    </td>



                        <td>
                            <div class="quantity">
        <input step="1" min="" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" type="number">
    </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                                        <input name="attribute_pa_setting" value="18-k-yellow-gold" type="hidden">
                                                        <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button btn btn-primary ajax_add_to_cart"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span> Add to cart</button>
                            <input name="variation_id" value="722" type="hidden">
                            <input name="product_id" value="719" type="hidden">
                            <input name="add-to-cart" value="719" type="hidden">


                        </td>


                        </tr>
                            <tr class="product-719 variation-723 wrapper" data-role="product"> 
                  <form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product_id="719" data-product_variations="null"></form>   
                    <td class="image">
                        <img src="https://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/1470935641.png" alt="Custom Key Blades-723" width="150px" height="150px">               </td>
                    <td class="title">
                        <h3>Custom Key Blades</h3><br>
                        <b>18 K White Gold  </b>
                        </td>

                    <td class="note">
                                            <label>Type Your Letter</label><input class="letter-note wh-input" name="_wholesale_letter" value="" maxlength="1" placeholder="TYPE 1 LETTER">             </td>   
                    <td class="price">
                        <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>1,000.00</span></span>                </td>
                    <td class="keyblade">
                        <table>
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <th>Schlage-SC1</th><td><input class="sc-note wh-input wh-qty" name="_wholesale_sc" value="" type="number"></td>                        </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <th>Kwikset-KW1</th><td><input class="kw-note wh-input wh-qty" name="_wholesale_kw" value="" type="number"></td>                        </tr>
                        </tbody></table>

                    </td>



                        <td>
                            <div class="quantity">
        <input step="1" min="" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" type="number">
    </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                                        <input name="attribute_pa_setting" value="18-k-white-gold" type="hidden">
                                                        <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button btn btn-primary ajax_add_to_cart"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span> Add to cart</button>
                            <input name="variation_id" value="723" type="hidden">
                            <input name="product_id" value="719" type="hidden">
                            <input name="add-to-cart" value="719" type="hidden">


                        </td>


                        </tr>
                            <tr class="product-719 variation-724 wrapper" data-role="product"> 
                  <form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product_id="719" data-product_variations="null"></form>   
                    <td class="image">
                        <img src="https://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Modern-Iconic-Key-with-Black-Diamond-.png" alt="Custom Key Blades-724" width="150px" height="150px">                </td>
                    <td class="title">
                        <h3>Custom Key Blades</h3><br>
                        <b>18 K Rose Gold  </b>
                        </td>

                    <td class="note">
                                            <label>Type Your Letter</label><input class="letter-note wh-input" name="_wholesale_letter" value="" maxlength="1" placeholder="TYPE 1 LETTER">             </td>   
                    <td class="price">
                        <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>950.00</span></span>                </td>
                    <td class="keyblade">
                        <table>
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <th>Schlage-SC1</th><td><input class="sc-note wh-input wh-qty" name="_wholesale_sc" value="" type="number"></td>                        </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <th>Kwikset-KW1</th><td><input class="kw-note wh-input wh-qty" name="_wholesale_kw" value="" type="number"></td>                        </tr>
                        </tbody></table>

                    </td>



                        <td>
                            <div class="quantity">
        <input step="1" min="" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" type="number">
    </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                                        <input name="attribute_pa_setting" value="18-k-rose-gold" type="hidden">
                                                        <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button btn btn-primary ajax_add_to_cart"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span> Add to cart</button>
                            <input name="variation_id" value="724" type="hidden">
                            <input name="product_id" value="719" type="hidden">
                            <input name="add-to-cart" value="719" type="hidden">


                        </td>


                        </tr>




                </tbody>


                </table>
```

***AND HERE IS THE JQUERY SCRIPT***

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js" integrity="sha256-zgND4db0iXaO7v4CLBIYHGoIIudWI5hRMQrPB20j0Qw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    var quantity = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input.wh-qty').each(function () {
            quantity += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $('input[name="quantity"]').val(quantity);

        $('input.wh-qty').on('input', function () {
            quantity = 0;
            $('input.wh-qty').each(function () {
                var amountInfo = parseInt($(this).val());
                amountInfo = (amountInfo) ? amountInfo : 0; 
                quantity += amountInfo;
            });
            $('input[name="quantity"]').val(quantity);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can give your `<tr class="product-<?php...` an attribute of `<tr data-role="product" class="product-<?ph` and then use jQuery to get and set values of each row:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input.wh-qty').on('input', function () {
    setQuantity();
  });
})
const setQuantity = function(){
  $.each(
    $(`tr[data-role="product"]`), // add role="product" to tr
    function(index,element){
      const $el = $(element);
      const sc = $el.find("input.sc-note.wh-qty").val();
      const kw = $el.find("input.kw-note.wh-qty").val();
      if(sc!=="" || kw!==""){
        $el.find('input[name="quantity"]').val(
          (sc*1)+(kw*1)
        );
      }
    }
  );
};
```

If that doesn't work could you please post the entire html so we don't need to puzzle together what the html is?

Comment: I have updated **GENERATED HTML CODE:** section with the full generated HTML Table. Is it enough or I need to post the full Page HTML?
This page main content is only this table.

Comment: yes the code is working now. But there is a small glitch happening.

Say I am increasing **PRODUCT 1 wh-qty** which increases **PRODUCT 1 quantity** fine but all the other products quantity becomes 0.

Comment: Here is the screenshot [link](https://imgur.com/a/lceAg) ;
Also is it possible to change the Price with the main quantity?
Like Price is 100 so when main quantity is 10 the price column will show 1000 instead of 100?

Comment: @shan404 I updated the answer so it should not set total to zero. If you want the total price you need to know the price of a single item. Where is the price of a single item in the html? If you say it's in `<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">` then how can I change this? After changing it I don't know the price of a single item anymore (at least not without a whole bunch of unnecessary code).

Comment: it's working now. Thank you so very very much for helping me out.
Before closing; 1) is it possible to make sc1/kw1 to become 0 auto while kw1/sc1 is only increasing? The fields usually is blank so when I only increase SC1 the KW1 remains blank; they are both required field which I validate by checking if they are blank or not? So if user tries to Add the Product it won't validate & give error after page refreshes.

Comment: 2) About Price: How are they doing it: [variation quantity](http://ppom.nmediahosting.com/product/woo-logo/) . Can I use like `$price = $product->get_price_html()` then use `$price` to update?

Comment: 3) Please see the [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/FxcHi) . After adding a product to the cart all of my custom field is showing the submitted value in all the products. Why it's happening? 
Thanks a lot @HMR